# Approximation of the length of the decimal representation of a type

Tags: c++, c, git, algorithm

When I read the source code of git, I am confused by this macro.

```
    /* Approximation of the length of the decimal representation of this type. */
    #define decimal_length(x)   ((int)(sizeof(x) * 2.56 + 0.5) + 1)
```

[The code is here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-compat-util.h#L119)

But when I try to calculate the approximation of the length of the decimal representation of a type, I think the answer is

```
    ((int)(sizeof(x) * 8 * ln2 ) + 1)
```

which could be write as

```
    ((int)(sizeof(x) * 2.41 ) + 1)
```

Could you tell me why the git calculates the length by "(sizeof(x) * 2.56 + 0.5)" instead of "(sizeof(x) * 2.41)"?
Thanks very much.

Comment: "Why is something designed this way" is not usually answerable on StackOverflow, because only the author can give a definitive answer.

Comment: I assume this is being used to calculate the maximum number of characters needed to print a signed integer of a given type. Your reasoning is correct. But as long as the calculation gives the right answer when `sizeof(x)` is 1, 2, 4, or 8, then it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Should be `((int)(sizeof(x) * 2.41 + 1.65))` to get the correct answer from 8-bit to 128-bit.

Comment: The macro overestimates the digit count when `sizeof(x)` is greater than 4, because the slope is too high.

Comment: To @RyanBemrose , I think you are right.  I searched the source code, and I found that this macro never be used. I think only the author can answer this question :)

Comment: @user3386109 ha, u give another right way to cal the length :).

Answer (score 3):

Seems like an opportunity for a bake-off!  Here are the results I get from four different number sizes:

```
A = (sizeof(x) * 2.56 + 0.5) + 1
B = (sizeof(x) * 2.41) + 1
C = (sizeof(x) * 2.41 + 1.65)

strlen  A   B   C   Number (bytes)

4       4   3   4   -127 (1)
6       6   5   6   -32767 (2)
11      11  10  11  -2147483647 (4)
20      21  20  20  -9223372036854775807 (8)
```

**Kudos to user3386109**.  All of these schemes attempt to estimate the maximum possible length, not the actual length (i.e. they don't care what value 'x' contains).  Below is the code I used to generate the above table.  I didn't include `long long` as on my system it's the same size as `long`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define decimal_length1(x) ((int)(sizeof(x) * 2.56 + 0.5) + 1)

#define decimal_length2(x) ((int)(sizeof(x) * 2.41) + 1)

#define decimal_length3(x) ((int)(sizeof(x) * 2.41 + 1.65))

int main() {

    char buffer[1024];

    char a = -127;
    short b = -32767;
    int c = -2147483647;
    long int d = -9223372036854775807L;

    printf("A = (sizeof(x) * 2.56 + 0.5) + 1\n");
    printf("B = (sizeof(x) * 2.41) + 1\n");
    printf("C = (sizeof(x) * 2.41 + 1.65)\n\n");

    printf("strlen\tA\tB\tC\tNumber (bytes)\n\n");

    sprintf(buffer, "%hhd", a);
    printf("%lu\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%s (%lu)\n", strlen(buffer), decimal_length1(a), decimal_length2(a), decimal_length3(a), buffer, sizeof(a));

    sprintf(buffer, "%hd", b);
    printf("%lu\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%s (%lu)\n", strlen(buffer), decimal_length1(b), decimal_length2(b), decimal_length3(b), buffer, sizeof(b));

    sprintf(buffer, "%d", c);
    printf("%lu\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%s (%lu)\n", strlen(buffer), decimal_length1(c), decimal_length2(c), decimal_length3(c), buffer, sizeof(c));

    sprintf(buffer, "%ld", d);
    printf("%lu\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%s (%lu)\n", strlen(buffer), decimal_length1(d), decimal_length2(d), decimal_length3(d), buffer, sizeof(d));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I ignored the negative number.